# Domain name backwards, still good?

Tags: domain, domain-name, domain-registration

I'm wondering if I buy a domain name the uses keywords backwards is almost as efficient as the "right way". For example, if I want the domain: "www.bluesocks.com", but that was occupied. Then I find that "www.socksblue.com" is available, will that domain be valuable for people searching for "blue socks"?

edit: I've created the question over at startups.com, here's the [link](http://startups.com/questions/27437/domain-name-backwards-still-good-e-g-bluesocks-com-socksblue-com)

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for a businessy website. http://startups.com/ runs on Stack Exchange and advertise heavilly around here. They can probably help you more than we can.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did not know about that site :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that.  However, what would your customers think of it?  If all you are worried about is search engines, the domain name itself is likely the least of your worries.

Have good solid page content and META tags to describe your page and site, and it's likely you'll win regardless of which domain name you choose.  If you have crappy non-search-engine-friendly pages, it won't matter how awesome your domain name choice is.

Comment: I have a site up and running, with good content and meta tags. But i'm wondering if it would help even more to have one more domain name containing my niches keywords. And just to have a redirection on that name to my existing site?

Comment: META tags don't really matter anymore.  You're out of date on your SEO knowledge.

Comment: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/